# Imageview in Listview cannot change at runtime in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am developing Android Application. In which i am having list view with text and image. i need to set the imageview visible at run time. ie. when i clicked the view it should appear and when i click next view previous view have to disappear and corresponding imageview in clicking view have to appear.

Now i am success in displaying text but i am strucking in appearance of imageview. Inside the onclick of item list i cannot set the resource for imageview

Below is my code.

```
    public class ListofCategory extends Activity{
ListView listview;
List<String> mycategoryId,mycategoryName;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.listofcategory);
    listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.category_listview);
    mycategoryId=new ArrayList<String>();
    mycategoryName=new ArrayList<String>();
    getData();
    listview.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this));
     //setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this));
}

    class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;

MyListAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.context=context;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mycategoryId.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {

     ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(context);
            if (view == null) 
            {

              view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mycategorylist, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.categoryname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    holder.categorycount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
    holder.arrow=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.arrow_imageview);
    view.setTag(holder);
 }
 else
 {
     holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
 }
     holder.categoryname.setText(mycategoryName.get(position));
     holder.categoryname.setTextSize(18.0f);
     //holder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);

     view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
            Problem occurs here..  This holder value ask me to change as final but here i cannot make holder to final
             holder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
            //finish(); 

         }
     });

 return view;
}


   }
 class ViewHolder
{
    TextView categoryname;
    TextView categorycount;
    ImageView arrow;

}

    }
```

Please anyone give me a better solution..its very urgent.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a final pointer for the imageView.

```
final ImageView tempView = holder.arrow;
```

than in the onclick:

```
tempView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
```

Added to the class a field:

```
MyListAdapter myAdapter;
```

In the oncreate method do this:

```
myAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this);
listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

On the onclick event do this:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    

     @Override    
     public void onClick(View v)    
     {    
        Problem occurs here..  This holder value ask me to change as final but here i cannot make holder to final    
         tempView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);    
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChange();    

     }    
 });
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. while using this code final problem is solved but the previous image which is visible is also visible when i clicked another list item.

Comment: You need to call adapter.NotifiyDataSetChange() for the data to refresh it self.

Comment: Where i have to use adapter.NotifiyDataSetChange(). since i didnt take object for adapter. when i override notifiyDatasetChange its remain same..

Comment: no..imageview not set to tempView..it remain listview alone..i think it refresh after adding image view too..

Comment: tempView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow); line code not working ie imageview not added in the listview.i think  after adding    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChange();    this line of code refresh the added imageview too..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ViewHolder tmpHolder = null;
if( view == null ) {
    .
    .
    .
    tmpHolder = new ViewHolder();
} else {
    tmpHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}
final ViewHolder holder = tmpHolder;

view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
         holder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
        //finish(); 

     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand,

I think instead of using `view onClickListener` use, the `layout onClickListener` which is used in `R.layout.mycategorylist`.

Or else, you can use `holder.categoryname onClickListener` or  `holder.categorycount listeners` right.

and You can declare `ViewHolder holder ; as global variable in your MyListAdapter` right, then there is no issue for declaring `final` or something.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            ImageView image;
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) view;//Layout of mycategorylist
            image = (ImageView) layout.getChildAt(0);//image is added first here.change accordingly
            image.setImageDrawable(....imageId);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     public class ListofCategory extends Activity{
ListView listview;
List<String> mycategoryId,mycategoryName;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.listofcategory);
    listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.category_listview);
    mycategoryId=new ArrayList<String>();
    mycategoryName=new ArrayList<String>();
    getData();
    listview.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this));
     //setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this));
}

    class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
private ImageView previous;

MyListAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.context=context;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mycategoryId.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {

     ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(context);
            if (view == null) 
            {

              view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mycategorylist, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.categoryname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    holder.categorycount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
    holder.arrow=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.arrow_imageview);
    view.setTag(holder);
 }
 else
 {
     holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
 }
     holder.categoryname.setText(mycategoryName.get(position));
     holder.categoryname.setTextSize(18.0f);
     //holder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);

     view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v)
         {

            if(previous!=null){

                previous.setVisibility(View.Invisible);
                v.setVisibility(View.Visible);
                previous = v;
        }
         }
     });

 return view;
}


   }
 class ViewHolder
{
    TextView categoryname;
    TextView categorycount;
    ImageView arrow;

}
```

Comment: In the above code previous is null.. since no imageview is assigned to previous.

Comment: thn how it came inside the condition for next time too..since no assignment for previous..

Comment: yes i have tried but it not allowing me to assign v to previous. showing error as final local variable cannot be assign.. when i remove final for previous it again showing error to declare as final..what to do? were i have done mistake??