# how to change the row content from inside the onclick method

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a complex row layout ("2 imageViews , 3 TextViews ") so i have defined my own adapter. i want to change the color for the textViews upon a click ! and i faced the problem of non final variable refered from inside an inner class is there any twist around this problem ?

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(convertView==null)
    {     minflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);


    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowtext1);
    holder.note = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowtext2);
    holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowtext3);
    holder.course= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowtext4);
    holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowimage1);
    holder.read = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowimage2);


    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        private int pos = position;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            numberOfClicks++;
                            // Heres the problem 
            holder.title.setTextColor();
            if(pos==0 &&  numberOfClicks % 2 ==1 )
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stoprow);
            else if  (pos==0 &&  numberOfClicks % 2 !=1 )
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toprow);


            else if (pos==getCount()-1 &&  numberOfClicks % 2 !=1 )
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottomrow);
            else
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.smiddlerow);
        }
        });





        convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
        // and the ImageView.
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

Comment: Don't use anonymous / inline `onClick` handlers. Have your `Activity` implement the `OnClickListener` it makes things so much more flexible.

Comment: what if i have many clickable row !! do i have to use switch statement and the system should go through it each time one item is clicked ? Here i'm implementing my onclick inside the getView

Comment: You can set the `onClick` method in the row layout file using the XML `android:onClick` attribute see - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick - doing this will mean all 'clicks' will fire the same method....and yes, you'll need to prcess the `View` to work out which one has been clicked. With a lot of rows, it seems more efficient to me to have one listener than many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i too got same problem and finally i got solution as follows

```
 final TextView tempView = holder.title;
```

than in the onclick:

```
  title.setTextColor();
```

Refer this link for further reference [Imageview in Listview cannot change at runtime in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978689/imageview-in-listview-cannot-change-at-runtime-in-android)